# Can one develop coded solutions in a Sales Cloud Essentials license?

Tags: licenses

As per the different pricing options for the Sales Cloud as per https://www.salesforce.com/uk/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/ and https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_gb/www/datasheets/uk-sales-cloud-pricing-comparison.pdf, the Sales Cloud Essentials licenses gives one access to a small number of standard objects but without any declarative automation nor without record types, profiles or permission sets.

Does the Sales Cloud Essentials license though support Apex and custom components? For example, can a develop deploy coded solutions to an org that is on the Sales Cloud Essentials org license or is that not feasible?

The documentation says that both Essentials and Pro don't support the Lightning Platform which would seem to suggest that coded solutions or custom objects are both not supported - such as described here - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BW0nIAG - but I wasn't sure for certain if that's the case or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used to include this in the marketing material, but if you check the [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_define_package.htm&type=5) topic for this, you'll see that only Enterprise and above gets Apex, and all Editions, aside from "Personal Edition", including Contact Manager, gets [Visualforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_creating.htm&type=5). Contact Manager appears to be the old branding for Essentials, so Visualforce should be included. However, note that compatible AppExchange apps published by ISVs can be installed in Essential orgs.